# Extend the event OnClick of all MenuItems in the screen to execute another block of code

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I want to set an event `OnClick` to all `TMenuItems` on the screen to do what the event currently does, and another few lines of code. I am currently using Delphi 5

For example, say that I have a `TMenuItem` with the code:

```
procedure TdesktopForm.MenuFoo1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(TComponent(Sender).Name)
end;
```

and I also have the following procedure:

```
procedure TdesktopForm.bar;
begin
  ShowMessage('extra')
end;
```

And I want to everytime I click the TMenuItem the program show the TMenuItem's name and also the 'extra' message.

The example shown is just a demonstration of my problem, as in the real software I have over 300 menu items, I want to do this generically, so I won't have to add extra lines of code to all current menu clicks, nor add them when I add new menu items. The order of execution (between the menu click and the extra block of code) doesn't matter.

I tried using `TActionList` but I couldn't retrieve the object triggering the action, hence, I can't print it's name. I tried using `ActiveControl` but it always return the focused currently focused object, not the actual menu that I clicked. And also, the `TAction` execute event overwrites my `TMainMenu.OnClick` event

Comment: IMHO If you really want to go this way TAction might be the better Option. Here are two places for handling it `TAForm.ActionList1Execute(Action: TBasicAction; var Handled: Boolean); begin Showmessage(Action.ActionComponent.Name); end;` or `procedure TAForm.AllActionsExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Showmessage(TAction(Sender).ActionComponent.Name);
end;`

Comment: I tried using `ActionComponent` but this property is inexistant in my `TAction`. I would guess it was introduced in a newer version than the one i'm using

Comment: Attach a wm_command handler, then you can duplicate the functionality that fires an item click

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as all your event handlers are assigned at some point (either at design time or at run time) and don't change afterwards, you can do something like this:

1. Enumerate all menu items in the menu
2. For each create an object like the one described below

   ```
   type
     TEventInterceptor = class(TComponent)
     private
       FOrigEvent: TNotifyEvent;
       FAdditionalEvent: TNotifyEvent;
       procedure HandleOnClick(_Sender: TObject);
     public
       constructor Create(_MenuItem: TMenuItem; _AdditionalEvent: TNotifyEvent);
     end;

   constructor TEventInterceptor.Create(_MenuItem: TMenuItem; _AdditionalEvent: TNotifyEvent);
   begin
     inherited Create(_MenuItem);
     FOrigEvent := _MenuItem.OnClick;
     FAdditionalEvent := _AdditionalEvent;
     _MenuItem.OnClick := HandleOnClick;
   end;

   procedure TEventInterceptor.HandleOnClick(_Sender: TObject);
   begin
     FOrigEvent(_Sender);
     FAdditinalEvent(_Sender);
   end;
   ```

Note that this code is completely untested and may not even compile.
I'm also not sure whether this works with Delphi 5. It does with Delphi 6 though, so chances are good.

Edit:
Some additional notes (thanks for the comments):

- Inheriting this class from TComponent makes the form free it automatically when it is being destroyed.
- HandleOnClick should possibly check if FOrigEvent is assigned before calling it.

Comment: Work completely as expected. Was trying to use wm_command as sugested in the comments, but i wasn't able to retrieve the handle back. Thank you for your effort on writing this snippet!

Comment: As a side note, I removed the `TComponent` inheritance for a better memory usage and simplicity, it also worked!

Comment: And maybe introduced a memory leak.. - how do your interceptor instances get destroyed if they are not "woned" by the menuitem? - also I would put an `If Assigned(FOrigEvent)`   before calling the `FOrigEvent` handler. For it may not have been assigned previously and would cause an AV otherwise.

Comment: "woned" -->"owned" - sorry time was up for editing, I'll review better before posting next time.

Comment: But as a `TComponent` child there's a hint about hiding the `Create` virtual method, and I can't override it since the parameter list differs

Comment: You can always keep the default constructor and add an additional method that does the rest. Or have plain procedure (not method), that creates the object, sets all its fields etc.

Comment: @RodolfoDonãHosp "*Was trying to use wm_command as sugested in the comments, but i wasn't able to retrieve the handle back*" - `WM_COMMAND` gives you the ID if the clicked menu item. You can convert that ID to a `TMenuItem` object pointer using [`TMenu.FindItem()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TMenu.FindItem) with `Kind=fkCommand`. When `TForm` processes `WM_COMMAND`, it calls `Menu.DispatchCommand()` with the item ID, which then calls `FindItem()` and then `TMenuItem.Click()` if found.